# How do I change the hostname defined on a WAS 7 profile?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have installed WebSphere Application Server v7 Stand-alone Edition. I have also created three application server profiles and one administrative agent profile. The hostname parameter was set to 'hostname' when creating these profiles. How can I update this parameter to the actual hostname of the machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wsadmin` tool to change the hostname. For instructions, see [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tagt_hostname.html) to the IBM Documentation for WAS 7.

You will need to repeat the process for each of the created profiles. Once the change is done, restart the servers for the changes to be correctly reflected.

Comment: I don't have a deployment manager so the link from IBM Documentation for WAS 7 is not relevant since most of the commands are not in wsadmin stand alone version.

Comment: @joe The same steps apply to your profiles, which are application server profiles and the admin agent profile. The `wsadmin` tool should be available at <profile_root>/bin.

Answer (score 0):

- Stop WAS
- Edit the file serverindex.html located under:

  @IBM_home$/profiles/$Server_name$/config/cells/$cell_name$/nodes/$node_name$
- Replace the old hostname with new hostname under all hostName and host definitions
- Start WAS